# Dúvida com função jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como esta função jQuery encontra a tag `em` para executar o método **prependTo()** ?

```js
var em;

$("#btn").click(function() {
   if (em) {
      em.prependTo("pre");
      em = null;
   } else {
      em = $("em").detach();            
   }
});
```

```css
em {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <em>Alô </em>
   <pre>como vai</pre>
   <em>você?</em>
   <button type="button" id="btn">Anexa/desanexa par&aacute;grafos</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Não encontra. A primeira condição será falsa (pois `false`, `null` e `undefined` são considerados falsos no JavaScript), isso fará com que o código pule para o `else`. O `detach` irá recortar o elemento `<em>` e atribuir à variável `em`, dessa forma ela deixará de ser falsa e passa a ser verdadeira. Na próxima vez que o botão sofrer uma ação de clique, a condição será verdadeira.

Comment: Certo cara, entendi. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não encontra no primeiro click, porque a princípio o `em` é apenas uma variável *null*.

Ao primeiro click do botão, o `em` é *false*, indo direto para o `else`, onde agora `em` passa a ter um valor (`em = $("em").detach();`), que é o elemento `<em>`.

No segundo click o `em` já será *true* e atenderá a condição do `if`. Fará o `prependTo` e `em` voltará a ser *null* novamente, e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: vou aceitar sua resposta :)

Comment: Obg! Se alguém postar uma resposta melhor, vc pode alterar a sua opção. Abs!

Comment: É que o Valdeir Psr ali em cima, já tinha explicado o funcionamento, mas, valeu!